# Why are some fields not editable in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Although I am logged in as Administrator user in pgAdmin4, and with an admin role inside my database, the edition fields are always disabled, as in:

[image]

So I can't make modifications with the interface.

Is there some knob to turn on somewhere to allow that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Got a response on the support mailing list, that I post here for reference*

Turns out this is wanted behavior: Postgresql does not offer a way to modify those fields on a constraint (see [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)), you have to drop/re-create the constraint. So the UI reflects that.